# DataTables - Accordian (Child Rows)

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am trying to get a DataTable working with the Bootstrap Accordian and I have successfully achieved this when there is one parent row with child rows.

```
 var rowData = {
    a: 'Accounting', 
    b: 2350.10,
    c: [
        '<tr class="accordian-body collapse 1collapsed"><td>H1</td><td>1000.00</td></tr>','<tr class="accordian-body collapse 1collapsed"><td>H2</td><td>950.00</td></tr>','<tr class="accordian-body collapse 1collapsed"><td>H3</td><td>400.10</td></tr>']
}; $(document).ready(function() { dt1 = $('#example').DataTable({
createdRow: function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
  $(row).addClass( 'accordion-toggle' ).attr('data-toggle', 'collapse').attr('id', 1 ).attr('data-target', '.1collapsed');} ,
    columns: [
        {data: 'a'},
        {data: 'b'},
    ],
});

// nodes
var childNodes = $();
for (var c of rowData.c) {
    childNodes = childNodes.add( c );
}    
// add row + children
dt1.row.add(rowData)
    .child(childNodes).show()     
    .draw(false);});
```

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DCCEvolution/14w8rpym/latest/)

HOWEVER
When I then add in a 2nd row with the respective children the DataTable will not load.

```
var rowData = [{
    a: 'Marketing', 
    b: 2350.10,
    c: [
        '<tr class="accordian-body collapse 1collapsed"><td>H1</td><td>1000.00</td></tr>','<tr class="accordian-body collapse 1collapsed"><td>H2</td><td>950.00</td></tr>','<tr class="accordian-body collapse 1collapsed"><td>H3</td><td>400.10</td></tr>']
},{
    a: 'Accounting', 
    b: 2350.10,
    c: [
        '<tr class="accordian-body collapse 1collapsed"><td>H1</td><td>1000.00</td></tr>','<tr class="accordian-body collapse 1collapsed"><td>H2</td><td>950.00</td></tr>','<tr class="accordian-body collapse 1collapsed"><td>H3</td><td>400.10</td></tr>']
}];var accordian = 1;$(document).ready(function() {
dt1 = $('#example').DataTable({
createdRow: function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
  $(row).addClass( 'accordion-toggle' ).attr('data-toggle', 'collapse').attr('id', 1 ).attr('data-target', '.1collapsed');} ,
    columns: [
        {data: 'a'},
        {data: 'b'},
    ],
});

// nodes
var childNodes = $();
for (var c of rowData.c) {
    childNodes = childNodes.add( c );
}    
// add row + children
dt1.row.add(rowData)
    .child(childNodes).show()     
    .draw(false); });
```

[JS FIDDLE 2](http://jsfiddle.net/DCCEvolution/7v2pbjqc/latest/)

What am I doing wrong? I am not sure if my JS array/object is not formed correctly but could also be the node coding. Can anyone help? I appreciate that the accordian numbering may be off which would cause them all to open at the same time but this will be fixed with the final version but I need to get more than one row.

Answer (score 0):

And the answer.....

Iterate through the node and row adds!

```
rowData.forEach(rowData => {
var childNodes = $();
for (var c of rowData.c) {
    childNodes = childNodes.add( c );
}    
// add row + children
dt1.row.add(rowData)
    .child(childNodes).show()     
    .draw(false); });
```

[JS FIDDLE #59](http://jsfiddle.net/DCCEvolution/7v2pbjqc/59/)